# Multiple users without resetting Android settings?

Tags: multi-user

I got a new device and have the opportunity to start from scratch. For privacy reasons I want to adopt the multi-user paradigm in which I would isolate certain apps from other apps using the multiple user feature from Android. This way I can keep social media apps away from financial, etc.

Creating a new user shew me that I literally have to start from scratch on the new profile. All my previous settings are gone. I really wish non-sensible things like display settings or quick buttons above the notifications would be transferred over. Honestly, everything from the settings, but Wifi, Bluetooth and account settings.

I don't care how (template profile, copying setting data?), I don't care if I have to fire up the `adb shell` for that, is there any way to take the pain from creating a new user account profile?

I'd like to be able to quickly get a comfortable new user profile to install new stuff into it without worrying too much. If setting up with a new profile involves many minutes (which it would right now), I would be too lazy and keep using a standard set of profiles which is less ideal for privacy reasons.